# Why does my code only work with these two empty print statements?

Tags: c, memory, heap, cpu-registers

```
void siftdown(struct heap *H, int i) {

      int pIndex, lcIndex;
      int siftKey = H->nodes[i];
      int spotFound = 0;
      pIndex = i;

       printf(" ");
      //  printf("first:%d ", H->size);

      while (2 * pIndex + 1 <= H->size - 1 && spotFound == 0) {
        if (2 * pIndex < H->size - 1 &&
            (H->nodes[2 * pIndex + 1] < H->nodes[2 * pIndex + 2])) {
          lcIndex = 2 * pIndex + 2;
          // printf("second:%d ", H->size);
        } else {
          lcIndex = 2 * pIndex + 1;
          // printf("third:%d ", H->size);
        }
        if (siftKey < H->nodes[lcIndex]) {
          H->nodes[pIndex] = H->nodes[lcIndex];
          pIndex = lcIndex;
          // printf("fourth:%d ", H->size);
        } else {
          spotFound = 1;
          // printf("fifth:%d ", H->size);
        }
      }
      H->nodes[pIndex] = siftKey;
    }
    void makeHeap(int n, struct heap *H) {
      H->size = n;
      printf(" ");
      // printf("sixth:%d ", H->size);
      for (int i = floor(n / 2); i >= 0; i--) {
        //printf("\n%d %d", i, H->nodes[i]);
        siftdown(H, i);
      }
    }`
```

Im doing a array implementation of a heap and between the makeHeap to siftDown pass the heaps size becomes 0, unless these two empty print statements are present.

Im assuming that the heap->size call is reading from a register rather than fetching from memory but I don't really know how to fix it.

Comment: You describe classic symptoms of undefined behavior resulting from a bounds overrun.

Comment: Could you please try to post a [mre] and review the code formatting?

Comment: "reading from a register rather than fetching from memory": why would you assume this?  Why would it matter?

Comment: Side note: your `n / 2` is an integer (truncating) division.  The result is already an integer, so passing it through `floor()` serves no useful purpose.

Comment: How have you defined `struct heap`? Have you allocated the necessary memory for `H->nodes`? With which code do you initialise the values and call your functions?

Answer (score 1):

You have an unchecked access to `H->nodes[2 * pIndex + 2]` in this part of your code:

```
  while (2 * pIndex + 1 <= H->size - 1 && spotFound == 0) {
    if (2 * pIndex < H->size - 1 &&
        (H->nodes[2 * pIndex + 1] < H->nodes[2 * pIndex + 2])) {
```

The condition `2 * pIndex < H->size - 1` is not the right one. This was already checked by the `while` condition, so when executed, this will always evaluate to true. You need to check whether the node has a *right* child, with this condition: `2 * pIndex + 2 < H->size`.

Because this is not checked, you may get into a situation where `lcIndex` is out of range, and eventually that makes `pIndex` out of range, leading to a *write* to that location with `H->nodes[pIndex] = siftKey;`. This results in undefined behaviour. For instance, if that memory location happens to be used by `size`, then this assignment alters the size.

I would also harmonise all these boundary checks, using `< H->size` and not `<= H->size - 1` and other variants.

Note a problem, but in `makeHeap` you don't need to `floor` as the division is an integer division. You can also do with one iteration less, starting at `n/2-1`.

So:

```
void siftdown(struct heap *H, int i) {
  int parentIndex = i;
  int childIndex = i * 2 + 1;
  int siftKey = H->nodes[i];

  while (childIndex < H->size) {
    if (childIndex + 1 < H->size && H->nodes[childIndex] < H->nodes[childIndex + 1]) {
      childIndex++;
    }
    if (siftKey >= H->nodes[childIndex]) {
      break;
    }
    H->nodes[parentIndex] = H->nodes[childIndex];
    parentIndex = childIndex;
    childIndex = 2 * parentIndex + 1;
  }
  H->nodes[parentIndex] = siftKey;
}

void makeHeap(int n, struct heap *H) {
  H->size = n;
  for (int i = n / 2 - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    siftdown(H, i);
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you check this solution? Did it solve your problem?